# Java bacnet4j communication over Network

Tags: java, network-programming, bacnet, bacnet4j

I am able to get my virtual bacnet4j devices up and running. as I am running them on One windows machine i have used set of ip address 127.0.0.3-10.

I have a virtual Bacnet device which monitors other devices, which work fine when its on address 127.0.0.2 (or any other address starting with 127.0.0.* )

However I am now puuting it (Monitor) on Actual different windows machine running on IP say 192.168.2.3
My machines IP address on that Networks is say 192.168.2.2

Now The Monitor and devices won't recieve any broadcasted messagesfrom each other.

Any idea's if its achievable? 
I have already tried using link service option within bacnet4j. 
Now thinking of writing a bacnet router myself to achieve this. but wanted to confirm if What i am thinking is right? or is  there a better way to achieve this communication.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious: Any firewall activated?
Can you ping the other machine? Just to cover the bases.

Comment: No Firewall.. I can Ping the other machine.

Comment: I can not run multiple devices on Address "192.168.2.2" on same port for obvious reasons (Port already in use. ). so my devices (virtual) using loopback addresses (127.0.0.3 127.0.0.4)   and my reciever address is 192.168.2.3 which  is on real network.

Comment: I am afraid there is not much I can do to help, since I am not able to recreate the problem. The only thing I can think about is: get a network sniffer running on both machines to isolate the fault. When this is done try to break down the networking stack if you can insert a trace facility. You can also try switching components to see what makes a difference.  Sorry I cannot help you more than this.